# Next.Js Not scroll to top on change router

Tags: next.js

nextjs documentation says to disable scrolling when the router changes, scroll: false option. I wrote this option but still scrolling to the top when the router changes. what did i write wrong?

my code

```
router.push({
    pathname: path,
    query: query,
    scroll: false
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I wrote a mistake here

```
router.push({
    pathname: path,
    query: query,
 }, undefined, { scroll: false });
```